# On UserManager.AddToRoleAsync: "New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I just started playing around with blazor.

I've got my first attempt on a user management system and trying to update the user roles to the selected roles in my ListBox.

All works fine until it reaches the following loop:

```
// On Initialisation
IEnumerable_AvailibleRoles = _RoleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name);

// On Save
foreach (string sIdentityRoleName in IEnumerable_AvailibleRoles)
{
    bool bUserIsInRole = await _UserManager.IsInRoleAsync(IdentityUser_User, sIdentityRoleName);

    if (bUserIsInRole && !IEnumerable_UserRoles.Contains(sIdentityRoleName))
    {
        // Remove user from role
        await _UserManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(IdentityUser_User, sIdentityRoleName);
    }

    if (!bUserIsInRole && IEnumerable_UserRoles.Contains(sIdentityRoleName))
    {
        // Put user in role
        await _UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(IdentityUser_User, sIdentityRoleName);
    }
}
```

The error appears on the first try of adding a user to a role.

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session. [StackTrace](https://ghostbin.co/paste/9kkb2)

Bevor the role update loop I just find the user, change it's parameters and save it.

```
// Get the user
IdentityUser_User = await _UserManager.FindByIdAsync(this.IdentityUser_User.Id);

// Update Email
IdentityUser_User.Email = this.IdentityUser_User.Email;

// Update the user
await _UserManager.UpdateAsync(IdentityUser_User);
```

But it doesn't make any difference if I save the user bevor or after the role loop.

Comment: What is `IEnumerable_AvailibleRoles` and how do you get it?

Comment: @GuruStron it's a `List<string>` which is filled with alls possible role names `IEnumerable_AvailibleRoles = _RoleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name);`

Comment: How you are creating transactions? Are you using TransactionScope?

Comment: @Thowk I don't know, I'm just using the methods made available by `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization`& `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess:

```
IEnumerable_AvailibleRoles = _RoleManager.Roles.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
IEnumerable_UserRoles = ... .ToList();
```

You seem to rely on IEnumerable a lot, do remember that means delayed exectution. Every time you call `.Contains(...)` it restarts that query.

Comment: I never used `IEnumerable` bevor. MS was using it in the Tutorial. So thanks for the tip.

Comment: And I need the `IEnumerable` for my DevExpress Control, so I'll have to do some more research on it :)

Comment: A `List<>` is an `IEnumerable<>` again, you should have no problems passing it on.